# ngx-infinite-scroll call function only 2 time?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use ngx-infinite-scroll in my angular project for pagination but when we scroll the window it is call function only one time. I am using 
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.2",
I did not find anything wrong in my code. 
my HTML file code is given below

```
<div
   infiniteScroll
   [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
   (scrolled)="getuserData()">
  ..............
</div>
```

Comment: ngx-infinite-scroll is highly dependent on your html and css. The viewport must be able to scroll freely and has to be marked with the directive. Please add a fiddle, stackblitz or whatever the youth is doing these days as to be able to help you.

Comment: thank you so much @GeckoIT  
you are right it's not working due to CSS  
I did not know it 's also depended on CSS